# set blob properties return an error

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to set cache control property of all uploaded blobs before, but it throws exception "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found."

```
 CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
              CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

        // Create the blob client.
        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

        List<CloudBlobContainer> containers = blobClient.ListContainers().ToList();

        // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(containerName);



        List<IListBlobItem>  blobs = container.ListBlobs().ToList();

        int count = 0;
        foreach (IListBlobItem blob in blobs)
        {
            CloudBlockBlob b = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blob.Uri.ToString());
            b.Properties.CacheControl = "public, max-age=1296000";
            b.SetProperties();

            Console.WriteLine("cached"+count.ToString());
            count++;
        }
```

The error is being thrown at SetProperties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a hierarchical listing, which can return virtual directories as well as blobs. For example, if you have a blob named "foo/bar" then your listing will return a CloudBlobDirectory named "foo/". When you try to use this as a blob name, the service retruns 404 because the blob does not exist.

To accomplish what you want, pass "useFlatBlobListing: true" to the call to ListBlobs and then cast each returned IListBlobItem to CloudBlob.